# Attach image to gmail

Tags: javascript, gmail

I have an app that open Gmail. I have to attach an image on email, but i don't know how. I tried to copy the HTML on the body of email, but Gmail don't read HTML.
How can I do?

Comment: Gmail reads html if you paste the outputted rich text to it.

Answer (score 1):

From [Uploading attachments](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/uploads)

> Example: Simple upload
>
> The following example shows the use of a simple upload request for the
>   Gmail API.
>
> ```
> POST /upload/gmail/v1/users/userId/messages/send?uploadType=media HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.googleapis.com
> Content-Type: message/rfc822
> Content-Length: number_of_bytes_in_file
> Authorization: Bearer your_auth_token
>
> Email Message data
> ```